# how to substitute the matched pattern with new pattern in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace the string which matches the following pattern:

```
my $string ="+++details of candidate 
           ++name of candidate
           +age of candidate
             +++idiot
                 +idi";
```

That string should be replaced with:

```
       my $string ="hii 
            how
           fine
            hii
            fine";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What would be the output if the input is `+++name of candidate` ?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. String replacement to generate HTML? I would suggest looking at the task of generating the HTML more closely would yield better results.

Comment: just hlp me to subsitiute the word

Comment: if it starts with  +++ it should replace with hiii

Comment: if it starts with ++ it should replace with how

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
$string =~ s/(\++)([^\+\n]*)/(qw(fine how hii))[length($1)-1]/ge;
```

Comment: _plus_1 for a genuinely hackish approach ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
$string =~ s/([^+]*)[+]+((\w+).*)([^ \r\n]*|$)/$1<div class="$3">$2<\/div>/g;
$string =~ s/ class="details"//g;
```

**Explanation**

- searches for a sequence of `+` ...
- ... , copies preceding charcaters other than `+` ...
- ... , appends content following the `+` sequence, wraps it in a `div` tag with a `class` attribute containing the first word of said content ...
- ... , where the end of 'content' is marked by a sequence of whitespace, line feed or carriage return; ...
- ... repeats that substitution effectively for every line and concats the results;
- In the second substitution, deletes the unwanted class attributes (in this case, 'details').

**Notes**

- The 'details' could have been singled out differently,eg. by counting the `+` characters.
- There are other possible solutions, in particular those employing advanced features of regex engines like positive lookbehind.

**Caveat**

- Consider the solution as it stands as a proof of concept:

  The specification of the context for substitutions in the regex crucially depends on the context in which the regex will be applied, ie. the set of potential strings against it will have to match.

  The pattern that you have provided is a small set of samples. Literally taken, the pattern would precisely be the set of strings you've provided. The generalisations expressed by the regex are my own assumptions on the actual nature of your pattern, of course.

**Update**

OP updated his question and requested a different replacement:

```
$string =~ s/[+]{3}((\w+).*)([^ \r\n]*|$)/hii/g;
$string =~ s/[+]{2}((\w+).*)([^ \r\n]*|$)/how/g;
$string =~ s/[+]{1}((\w+).*)([^ \r\n]*|$)/fine/g;
```

The order by decreasing length of `+` sequences in the pattern is significant.

Comment: just hlp me to subsitiute the sentence
if it starts with +++ it should replace with hiii

Comment: consider the sentence :

Comment: please help me to new question given above